# CodeIgniter with database selection:

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables `questions` and `answers`. In table `questions` there are two columns `id` and `que`. In table `answers` columns are `id`, `que_id`, option1, `optoin2` `option3`, `option4`. I want to print question and then its options.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('questions');
$this->db->join('answers', 'answers.que_id = questions.id', 'left');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

after this code I get print 4 times question with its options.

Comment: I want to print question once and then its options...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the join method will not help you in this case.

Try this:

```
$questions = $this->db->select('*')->from('questions')->get()->result();

foreach ($questions as &$question) {
    $question->answers = $this->db->select('*')->from('answers')->where('que_id', $question->id)->get()->result();
}
```

Now you can navigate through the $questions object and get the respective answers.

Hope I've helped a little.

Comment: how to get question and its options in view file. Because I don't want to use sql queries in view file as it should be written in model or controller.

Comment: Use a foreach loop to cycle through the $questions and then through the answers:

    <?php foreach ($questions as $question): ?>
        <h1><?= $question->que ?></h1>
        <ol>
            <?php foreach ($question->answers as $answer): ?>
                <li><?= $answer->option ?></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

You should change your answers' table structure, btw. You should have 1-N relationships between answers and questions.

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
$this->db->select('answers.option1,answers.option2,answers.option3,answers.option4,questions.que');
$this->db->from('answers');
$this->db->join('questions', 'answers.que_id = questions.id');
$query = $this->db->get();
```